# Is there a way to fix the code point too high problem in Perl Tk?

Tags: perl, utf-8, tk-toolkit

The following code demonstrates my problem. Running it gives me the error message that reads:"UCS-2LE:code point "\x{20541}" too high at C:/Perl/site/lib/Tk/Widget.pm line 205. at E:\test.pl line 9".

my Tk version is 804.028 and I'm running ActivePerl 10.0.0 on WinXP (Simplified Chinese version).

Does anyone know if there's a way around it? Thanks like always :)

```
use strict;use warnings;
use utf8;
use Tk;

my $mw = MainWindow->new;
my $text = ""; #A Chinese character

eval{
    $mw->Label(-text => $text)->pack;
};
warn $@ if $@;

MainLoop;
```

Comment: This may be a hex/decimal issue, as U+20541 is indeed invalid.  The character `倽` is *decimal* 20541, but it's [U+503D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/503d/index.htm).

Comment: @dkarp: U+20541 is a perfectly valid Unicode character (), it's just outside of the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), and doesn't fit in 16 bits.  Since Tcl/Tk stores Unicode characters as UCS-2LE (fixed 16 bits per character), it can't store this character.  Full Unicode is on the [wishlist](http://wiki.tcl.tk/883) (#92).

Comment: @mscha: Unicode only goes up to 0x10FFFF, and 0x20541 is bigger than that.  There are only 17 planes, not 33.

Comment: Not sure in what universe 0x20541 is bigger than 0x10FFFF, but here's the character from the OP: http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/u20541 and more on the planes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29

Comment: Crap, you're right.  I read an extra hex digit into the value.  Instead, looks like it's a UCS-2 issue, as UCS-2 can't encode outside the BMP.

Comment: Yup, I read an extra digit there, too. Bizarre! I guess it’s the old problem of “1, 2, 3, many”, where anything over three is perceived as a bunch. In regular writing, but not programming, one could use commas or thin spaces between groupings in long digit‐strings like “1048575”, like “1,048,575” or “1 048 575”.  But not many programming languages put up with anything like that: I don’t know if anything but Perl allows “1_048_575” and “0x10_FFFF”. However, there does exist [a well‐reasoned proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-April/001628.html) for Java to do so.

Comment: @mscha, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @tchrist: Yep, figured something like that :-)  I've always liked the underbars-in-numbers feature of Perl.  That, and allowing trailing commas in a list.  Makes for much easier code readability and maintenance.  I think C++ allows trailing commas now, too, but many language designers don't consider things like that.

Comment: @mscha, thanks. Your comment is really explanatory. If it were not a comment, I'd have accepted it as the answer to my question. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tk doesn't currently support Unicode characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (i.e., up to U+00FFFF). While there is a plan to fix this, it requires changing a great many things inside the Tk code (because a new string management layer has to be done in order for things to be efficient, plus there's a need to really sort out the normalization) so it's not being worked on in a great hurry. I'm sure that if someone were to offer assistance with sorting this out, it would be welcome.

However, if you think your character should *not* be outside the BMP (I can't tell from your question, sorry to say) then you've got some other encoding problem in your code. One way to diagnose this is to get the value from the [Unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) since they're properly complete and definitive and we can then make sure that what we're talking about is the same thing.